# How to batch insert text on photos?

Tags: linux, images

I am on linux/Ubuntu and wondering what is the easiest way to add copyright text to a couple of jpeg images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ImageMagick can add text to images. It probably comes pre-installed on Ubuntu. An example of how to use it from their website:

```
  convert dragon.gif -gravity south \
          -stroke '#000C' -strokewidth 2 -annotate 0 'Faerie Dragon' \
          -stroke  none   -fill white    -annotate 0 'Faerie Dragon' \
          anno_outline.jpg
```

This puts the text at the bottom of `dragon.gif`, creating a new image `anno_outline.jpg`. There are lots of text effects that you can read about in the `convert` documentation.

If you are only doing a couple of images you don't really need a batch file, but if you are doing more, say a whole directory, you can just wrap the command in a `for-do` loop:

```
for FILE in *.jpg; do convert $FILE -gravity south -annotate 0 'copyright' new_$FILE; done
```

Comment: Great help. just 'do echo' does not work. You need to modify the batch command to something like this: for FILE in *.jpg; do convert $FILE -gravity southeast -stroke '#000C' -strokewidth 2 -annotate 0 'copyright' -stroke  none   -fill white    -annotate 0 'copyright' new_$FILE; done

Comment: I fixed the command, removing the `echo`. I'd put it in just to test that the script was correct and forgot to remove the `echo` before posting!

Comment: i think it would be nice if you broke down what the command did, but I agree the effect however it works is pretty cool.

Comment: also that the bottom command is different from the top is slightly confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Image Magick and its [convert command](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/convert.html). It'll be something like:

```
convert -caption "(c) 2012 Mr. Photographer" original.jpg copyrighted.jpg
```

(Diving deeper into Image Magick docs will show ways to do this in bulk so that you can specify something like `*.jpg` for input files and the output files can be a variant on the original file name so that a.jpg becomes a-copyright.jpg, b.jpg -> b-copyright.jpg, etc)